# Spacing in Navigation Bar

Tags: next.js, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a simple Navigation Bar to my sample project.
It works well - but the separate links (Cases, Referrals) are stuck together.

How can I change the styling to make them a bit more spaced out? Where am I going wrong?

```
"use client";

import Link from "next/link";
import { Navbar, Nav, Container } from "@/components/bootstrap";

export default function NavigationBar() {
  return (
    <Navbar
      bg="primary"
      variant="dark"
      sticky="top"
      expand="sm"
      //collapseOnSelect
    >
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand as={Link} href="/">
          The Platform
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="main-navbar"></Navbar.Toggle>
        <Navbar.Collapse id="main-navbar">
          <Nav.Link href="/Cases">Cases</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="/Referrals">Referrals</Nav.Link>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I think your question has to be clearer.

if your links are all stuck together. try to make spaces with CSS styling. you can use **padding** on each link tag or you can use **margin** as well.

another thing you can use is to make sure your link tags are inline so they will have a width equal to their content.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `<Nav>` around the `<Nav.Link>`. I edited your code like this:

```
<Navbar
 bg="primary"
 variant="dark"
 sticky="top"
 expand="sm"
>
<Container>
    <Navbar.Brand as={Link} href="/">
        The Platform
    </Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="main-navbar"></Navbar.Toggle>
    <Navbar.Collapse id="main-navbar">
        <Nav>
            <Nav.Link href="/Cases">Cases</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="/Referrals">Referrals</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
</Container>
```